Crunchy Postgresql Backup configuration
I am trying to set up a backup for minio S3 but failing on the job
I would say that it probably  a certificate issue
I am using Gardner cloud and I have S3 storage provided from the cloud provider via a custom resource. After create the S3 custom resource, a secret is created for the bucket  with all the info to connect to it like key bucket name, key id, key secret, endpoint and certificate bundle.
I can use all that info in the kustomize yaml file beside the certificate bundle so I was. supposing that might be the issue:
apiVersion: postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/v1beta1
kind: PostgresCluster
metadata:
  name: service-1
  namespace: postgres
spec:
  image: registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/crunchy-postgres:ubi8-16.2-0
  postgresVersion: 16
  instances:
    - name: pgha1
      replicas: 3
      dataVolumeClaimSpec:
        accessModes:
        - "ReadWriteOnce"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
  backups:
    pgbackrest:
      image: registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/crunchy-pgbackrest:ubi8-2.49-0
      configuration:
      - secret:
          name: s3-bucket-postgres-service-2-0
      global:
        repo1-path: /pgbackrest/repo1
        repo2-s3-key: "..."
        repo2-s3-key-secret: "..."
        repo2-s3-region: "default"
      repos:
      - name: repo1
        schedules:
          full: "*/10 * * * *"
          incremental: "*/5 * * * *"
        volume:
          volumeClaimSpec:
            accessModes:
            - "ReadWriteOnce"
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 2Gi
      - name: repo2
        s3:
          bucket: "..."
          endpoint: "..."
          region: ""
  proxy:
    pgBouncer:
      image: registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/crunchy-pgbouncer:ubi8-1.21-3
      replicas: 3

There is no cronjob created,no errors logs...What should I look for to debug this ?
I am using latest crunchy postgres helm chart operator 5.5.1 postgres version 16
kubernetes version 1.26.8

UP ...........?
